# Binding class method to this in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sort of new to React and just started reading the **Road to learn React** free ebook. Anyway there is a part in the book where it says that in order to access *this* inside a class method, we need to bind class method to *this*. An example that is provided there clearly shows that:

```
class ExplainBindingsComponent extends Component {
    onClickMe() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    render() {
      return (
         <button
           onClick={this.onClickMe}
            type="button"
           >
          Click Me
        </button>
    );
  }
}
```

when the button is clicked, *this* is undefined, and if I add a constructor with this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.onClickMe = this.onClickMe.bind(this);
}
```

I can access *this* inside a method. However, I am now confused because I'm looking at an example where there's no binding and *this* is accessible:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       list,
    };

  }

  onDismiss(id) {
    console.log(this);
    const updatedList = this.state.list.filter(item => item.objectID !== id);
    this.setState({list: updatedList});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.list.map(item => 
             <div key={item.objectID}>
                <span>
                  <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                </span>
                <span>{item.author}</span>
                <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
                <span>{item.points}</span>
                <span>
                     <button
                         onClick={() => this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}
             type="button"
                     > 
             Dismiss
                     </button>
                </span>
              </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside **onDismiss** I can print *this* without any problems, although I didn't bind it ? How is this different from the first example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause of these four characters:

```
 () =>
```

Thats an arrow function. Unlike regular functions, they don't have their own context (aka `this`) but rather take the one of their parent (`render()` in this case) and that has the right context.

Comment: Yeah, my understanding was the the arrow function would take the context and that it would be accessible inside its body, however, onDismiss is just called inside an arrow function. Didn't know it would 'inherit' from the arrow function. Thanks.

Comment: to make this work babel-plugin-transform-class-properties is needed.

Comment: @hannad nope. This has nothing todo with class properties!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare as a function using `() =>` it automatically binds itself to `this`.

Take a look here:
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Comment: this may not work because his project may not have babel-plugin-transform-class-properties